# Identify as an injection, surjection, bijection or non-function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Identify as an injection, surjection, bijection, or non-function, where f:A->B with x an element of A, and the value of f is determined byL

f(x)=the address number of x A={houses} B={natural numbers}

Would this be an injection because each house corresponds to a unique address number, but not every address number is necessarily used?

Comment: You haven't accepted an answer in nearly two months even though you've been asking question throughout this period of time.

Comment: It's not the same thing. Neither is mandatory, but both are desirable behaviors (depending on the circumstances). Recall [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028599/logic-negate-and-simplify#comment2097080_1028599) comment for some links on information about this.

Comment: I vote up many answers though

Comment: alright I have began accepting answers. My apologies for not knowing how to earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation you described does not fit any of the four options you gave.  This relation is definitely a function, as an element of A cannot map to more than one element of B.  That is, a "house" cannot have more than one "address number."  The function is not injective, though, as more than one element of A can map to the same element of B.  That is, more than one house can have the same address number.  You could make this function injective by stipulating that all the houses must be on the same street, for example, in which case no two houses could have the same house number.  You're correct that the function isn't surjective, as there are elements of the codomain B which are not elements of the range of the function (there exist natural numbers that are not house numbers).  By definition, then, the function is also not bijective.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent concise explanation, thank you!